# Saxon XSLT SQL connection

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I have this html which I want to parse into sections and insert into an SQLite database:

```
     <html lang="en">
         <head>
             <title>Title</title>
         </head>
         <body data-ret-date="2023-08-04">
             <h1 data-toc="1" data-callcode="Title1">Title 1—General</h1>
             <h2 data-toc="5" data-callcode="Title1Part1">PART 1—DEFINITIONS</h2>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part1Sec1">§ 1  Definitions.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part1Sec1.1">§ 1.1  Foo.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h2 data-toc="5" data-callcode="Title1Part2">PART 2—THE COMMITTEE</h2>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part2Sec2">§ 2  Definitions.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part2Sec2.1">§ 2.1  Foo.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h2 data-toc="5" data-callcode="Title1Part3">PART 3—THE COUNCIL</h2>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part3Sec3">§ 3  Definitions.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
             <h3 data-toc="9" data-callcode="Title1Part3Sec3.1">§ 3.1  Foo.</h3>
             <p>foo</p>
             <p>foo</p>
         </body>
    </html>
```

I have this functioning stylesheet:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
        extension-element-prefixes="sql" 
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    
    <xsl:variable name="driver" select="'org.sqlite.JDBC'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="database" select="'jdbc:sqlite:/home/paul/topics/text.sqlite'"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="html">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="head"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:variable name="rdate" select="/html/body/@data-ret-date"/>
    
        <xsl:if test="not(element-available('sql:connect'))">
            <xsl:message>sql:connect is not available</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
    
        <xsl:message>Connecting to <xsl:value-of select="$database"/>...</xsl:message>
    
        <xsl:variable name="connection" as="java:java.sql.Connection"
            xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type">
            <sql:connect driver="{$driver}" database="{$database}">
                <xsl:fallback>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">SQL extensions are not installed</xsl:message>
                </xsl:fallback>
            </sql:connect>
            <xsl:message>Connected...</xsl:message>
        </xsl:variable>
    
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[@data-toc]">
            <xsl:variable name="text">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:variable>
    
            <sql:insert connection="$connection" table="textt">
                <sql:column name="callcode" select="@data-callcode"/>
                <sql:column name="text_id" select="0"/>
                <sql:column name="child_of" select="0"/>
                <sql:column name="rdate" select="$rdate"/>
                <sql:column name="txt_string" select="$text"/>
            </sql:insert>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    
        <sql:close connection="$connection"/>
        <xsl:message>Connection closed..</xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- transform with Oxygen 17, Saxon 9.6 PE, and the following config file
        
        <configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" edition="EE">
            <global allowExternalFunctions="true" versionOfXml="1.0"/>
            <xslt>
                <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
                 factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
             </xslt>
        </configuration>
    -->
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The end result is partially successful. The rows are inserted as plain text, but the HTML is stripped away, it is lost in the connection. I want the SQL column of `txt_string` to contain text and HTML. I know the variable `$text` contains the HTML, but it is lost.

I don't know if there is something that can be done. It is possible I shouldn't be using SQLite in this workflow. I may have to try an XML database such as ExistDB or BerkeleyDB.

(I tried to make text CSV files, and text SQL script files, but the workarounds to escape the quotes, commas, and line feeds were untenable)

Comment: With current versions of Saxon I would suggest to try to use the XPath 3.1 `serialize` function e.g. `<sql:column name="txt_string" select="serialize(current-group(), map { 'method' : 'xhtml' }"/>`. As your comments suggest you are using Saxon 9.6 PE I suggest you check its documentation whether there is an extension function to serialize nodes.

Comment: The docs https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/functions/saxon/serialize.html suggest you could try `select="string-join(current-group()/saxon:serialize(., 'xhtml'), '')"` for the `sql:column name="txt_string"`. Untested. And I think you need to make sure you have `xsl:output name="xhtml" method="xhtml"` in the XSLT code.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'm working it now.

Comment: Did the suggestion with `saxon:serialize` work with Saxon PE 9.6?

Comment: I changed the stylesheet to 3.0 and was able to use `string-join($text/serialize(.,$serial-params/*),'')`. I had trouble with the second argument for `serialize()` I set up a variable with the parameters. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`$text` doesn't contain "the HTML", it contains the node tree that results from parsing the HTML. In general if you use a node in a context where a string is expected, you're going to get the string value of the node, not a serialization into XML or HTML.

As Martin says, you need to serialize the node tree as HTML (or XHTML, or XML) and write the serialized form to the database. Depending on your processor version, you can do that with saxon:serialize or fn:serialize. You may need to move to a later version of Oxygen, which will include a later version of Saxon.

Comment: I tried to serialize and learned I have outdated tools.

Comment: I changed the stylesheet to 3.0 and was able to use `string-join($text/serialize(.,$serial-params/*),'')`. I had trouble with the second argument for `serialize()` I set up a variable with the parameters. Thanks for your help.